# Drop rows based on values located in the row below from the same group | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with four columns and I need to write a function that drops rows from dataframe grouped by 'ID'. I need to process each record (let's say `cur_row`) in the group like this:

If there is `cur_row`'s 'Acceptable year' value in any of the other rows' 'Cur.year' column, get the row where the value is found (let's say `found_row`) and check `found_row`'s 'Bool' column. If it's set to 'True', preserve the `cur_row`. Otherwise, drop it.

```
ID    |Cur.year| Bool    | Acceptable year
----------------------------------------
1     |  2020  |  True   | 2019   # Dropped since there is no '2019' in 'Cur.year'
1     |  2017  |  True   | 2016   # Not dropped since there is a '2016' record with 'True' bool
1     |  2016  |  True   | 2015   # Dropped since there is a '2015' record but with 'False' bool
1     |  2015  |  False  | 2014   # Not dropped, there is a '2014' record with 'True' bool
1     |  2014  |  True   | 2013   # Dropped
```

I know I have to use the groupby function but I can't get past this. Would you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Are all of the requirements ID-group-specific? 2. What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: @timgeb 1. The requirements are the same for all groups. 2. I have no idea how to get the row with 'Acceptable year' value in 'Cur.year' column and check its 'Bool'.

Comment: @timgeb No, it cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better performance not filtering per groups.

Create custom function per groups by mapping and use it for filtering:

```
def f(x):
    x['new'] = x['Acceptable year'].map(x.set_index('Cur.year')['Bool'])
    return x

df2 = df[df.groupby('ID').apply(f)['new'].fillna(False)]
print (df2)
   ID  Cur.year   Bool  Acceptable year
1   1      2017   True             2016
3   1      2015  False             2014
```

Or use `left join`:

```
df1 = df.merge(df, left_on=['ID','Acceptable year'], right_on=['ID','Cur.year'], how='left')

df2 = df[df1['Bool_y'].fillna(False)]
print (df2)
   ID  Cur.year   Bool  Acceptable year
1   1      2017   True             2016
3   1      2015  False             2014
```

Comment: Thanks! I have used the merge version since it's much faster when a large data set is used.

Comment: @JanValušek - You are welcome, pozeram, ze mas slovenske alebo ceske meno?

Comment: Ano, jsem z Česka. Ještě jednou moc díky!

Comment: @JanValušek - Super!

Answer (score 2):

Define a function that works on a single dataframe, then apply it to each group.

```
def drop_years(df):
    keep = df.set_index('Cur.year')['Bool']
    mask = df['Acceptable year'].map(keep).fillna(False)
    return df[mask]
```

This assumes that the values in the `'Cur.Year'` column are **unique per group**. If not, you could use

```
keep = df.set_index('Cur.year')['Bool'].to_dict()
```

This does not require groupwise-unique values in the `'Cur.Year'` column,
but might still lead to an incorrect result if the `'Cur.Year'` column contains duplicates with **different corresponding boolean values** in the `'Bool'` column in the same group.

Demo:

```
>>> df 
   ID  Cur.year   Bool  Acceptable year
0   1      2020   True             2019
1   1      2017   True             2016
2   1      2016   True             2015
3   1      2015  False             2014
4   1      2014   True             2013
>>> df.groupby('ID').apply(drop_years).reset_index(drop=True) 
   ID  Cur.year   Bool  Acceptable year
0   1      2017   True             2016
1   1      2015  False             2014
```

Comment: Ya, I edit answer - similar solution, but because filtering per groups it is slowier.

Comment: @jezrael I saw that you had a similar solution while I was still typing mine but that you filled the missing values at a different place.

Comment: Ya, and also filtering is different - You filter per groups, and my answer filtering complete DataFrame.